# How to configure Kamailio with SEMS

Tags: sip, voip, kamailio

I am working on Push To Talk PoC. I intent to use Kamailio as SIP signaling to work with SEMS for handling mixer conference audio (media server). The reason to use SEMS is performance is better in comparing with FreeSwitch or Asterisk. There are some guide to config Kamailio with Freeswitch or Asterisk but no for SEMS.

If you have any information or guide line, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annus Fictus  from Kamailio mail list send me this document. I follow the document and setup successful system. Just share here for another. The document in Spain. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Zc1BSbG4VwcDlyS1dSc2ZfeWVTTTVpOHZYcWFJa05KMVdn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please close the question if above answer might be the correct one.